# Aerodrome actual weather - METAR decode - 3 letters for this sky?

Tags: weather, metar

How can I describe this sky, in 3 letters as per [the Aerodrome actual weather - METAR  decode](http://www.para-excellence.co.uk/Taf%20Metar%20decode.html)?

I found online [a comprehensive list of Metar codes](http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/wrh/metar_decode_key.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Looks like Broken (BKN) to me, but you also need to provide base altitude, so just BKN doesn't accurately describe the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This work sheet may be of use](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/education/yos/resource/JetStream/synoptic/clouds_max.htm) and generally the system of [Okta is used to denote coverage in a Metar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta), but I would say

> L1 Clouds: Cumulus (Cu) with little vertical extent

but it could also be

> L5 Clouds: Stratocumulus (Sc) not from spreading out of Cumulus (Cu)

But I will agree with Ron on this one, its **BKN** ([5-6 Okta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta) based on the picture in my opinion)

Comment: Looks scattered to me